# mysql workbench 8.0 consulta select repeat. Deja la linea abierta como si no hubiera terminado la consulta. Aunque termina perfectamente

Tags: select

uso mysql workbench 8.0
Me ocurre que cuando lanzo una consulta simple select con la función repeat,
Ejemplo: select repeat(id,10) as id from producto;

La consulta resuelve bien, pero si doy al intro varias veces, me aparece la linea vertical (que aparece a la izquierda con un circulo arriba) como si no se hubiera terminado la consulta y estuviese esperando mas valores a introducir (por favor ver imagen para mas aclaración).

Esto solo me ocurre cuando el select va acompañado de un repeat.
con el resto de instrucciones select que he probado despues de resolverse el select, no aparece esa linea vertical como esperando mas parámetros.
¿por que ocurre esto? ¿si es normal? y si no lo fuera como solucionarlo?
Muchas gracias!
[image: imagen aclaracion consulta select]

Comment: ¿Hay más cosas arriba de esa instrucción? ¿Qué significan el `91` y el `92`? ¿Son números de línea?

Comment: Si, 91, 92, son números de línea, lo que hay mas arriba son comentarios